# php validation on a empty field

Tags: php, forms, validation

hi guys i am kinda new to php and i am trying to add validation on to the form. i want it so the form will not submit if it is empty.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="category_created.php">
Enter a New Category Name : 
<label for="cat"></label>
<input type="text" name="cat" id="cat" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and the form is being submitted to the file where the contents is being submitted to the database:

```
<?php
//category name received from 'new_category.php' is stored in cariable $cat
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$qry=mysql_query("INSERT INTO category(category)VALUES('$cat')", $con);
if(!$qry)
{
die("There Was An Error!". mysql_error());
}
else
{
echo "<br/>";
echo "Topic ".$cat." Added Successfully";
echo "<br/>";
}
?>
```

any help will be appreciated

thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You have to examine the value of `$_POST['cat']`. If it is empty, do not continue with the db update, but give error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `onsubmit` and validate like below

```
<form onsubmit="return validate()" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="category_created.php" >
 .....

 </form>
```

and in javasctipt

```
<script>
function validate(){

if(document.getElementById('cat').value.length<1)
{
alert('Please enter the Category Name');
return false;
}
else
{
return true;
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: any chance you could quickly just give overview of what the java script does and how it works?

Comment: cheers dude that works it doesnt let me add anything@user790454?please

Comment: simple,when you submit the form then the `onsubmit=return validate()` will be executed and the validation will be performed and if it returns `false` then the form will not be submitted and if it return `true` then the form will be submitted

Comment: how can i print out an error message if the field is empty? @user790454

Comment: see my modifed answer,i've added alert in javascript

Comment: if you think that my answer helps you then please make it as answer,so it'll be helpful for the others,all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

or you could submit the form via ajax, in the db-file you check whether the fields are empty, ifso echo an error message and print it via javascript. By doing this you can style everything the way you want to :)